# Can I use a push button switch to operate an actuator?

Tags: switching, actuator

Please forgive me if my question is just silly. I'm really struggling to find answers.

I have bought what I believe to be a DPDT switch. It is however a push button switch. It is an 8 pole switch with 2 simply because the switch is lit. My issue is I need to use it to operate an actuator and I need the push button because it needs to be used behind a cabinet door, pushing the door to operate the switch.

Wired correctly (as I have been told,) I cannot get the poles to reverse  (the actuator to retract.)

The wiring configuration is simply using the centre terminal NO1 for the load (the actuator in this case) with power running to all 6 other terminals. Direct to the light and NC1 then bridged and polarity reversed from NC1 to the C1 terminals. I guess I'n showing my level of knowledge with my explanation. I was under the impression in purchasing the switch that upon pressing I could wire it to start the actuator, and upon depressing the switch the actuator would close. (Poles reverse) Hopefully someone can help.

Am I simply trying to use a switch that cannot be used here? Again, forgive me, learning and many tell me this switch works but as I try to explain.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You have some terminology mixed up. Please provide a photo of the switch and a link to the datasheet. You haven't even provided a part number.

Comment: Hi.  I'm having a problem understanding _"...that upon pressing i could wire it to start the actuator, and upon depressing the switch the actuator would close."_  Ah! Do you mean _releasing_ rather than _depressing_ and does _close_ mean _retract_?

Answer (score 1):

To reverse polarity the switch should be wired as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvfZST.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The switch should be momentary - push button to actuate, release button to de-actuate.  A latching switch (push-on/push off) switch will not work.

Note that with this circuit, the load will always consume power.  If you just need to provide a brief pulse to actuate or de-actuate the device, a more complex circuit will be required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the exact type of pushbutton switch.

Momentary contact switch: push to turn on, release to turn off

Push-on, push-off switch: push to turn on, push again to turn off

Push-pull switch: push to turn on, pull to turn off

Normally-Open (NO) contact: Open when off, closed when on

Normally-Closed (NC) contact: Closed when off. open when on

You may need a continuity tester to determine how the switch functions.